# How to filter pandas rows based on if column values are substring of a given string?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `A`.
There is a given string `s`.

I want to subset the dataframe with rows which have column values in `A` which are substrings of
given string `s`.
If I wanted the other way around, I would have done something like `df[df['A'].contains(s)]`.
But I want to filter out rows where `s` is a superstring of value in `df['A']`.
I have not been able to find an answer to this hence apologies in advance if a duplicate question exists.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sample example:

```
s = 'sas'
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':['s', 'a', 'sa', 'da']})
```

The solution is:

```
filtered_df = df[[s.find(i)!=-1 for i in df['A'].values]]
```

It isn't a pandas way, but it works. I hope it will be helpful.

Output:

```
    A
0   s
1   a
2  sa
```

**UPD**: If you don't want to add rows where s==i, you can modify this code like:

```
df[[((s.find(i)!=-1) and (s!=i)) for i in df['A'].values]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do better than a list comprehension:

```
df[[x in s for x in df.A]]
```

However, if `df.A` is repetitive (e.g. a categorical) then you could optimize it

```
key, unique_vals = pd.factorize(df.A)
mask = np.asarray([x in s for x in unique_vals])
df.loc[mask[key]]
```

Or if `df.A` is a categorical

```
key, unique_vals = df.A.cat.codes, df.A.cat.categories
mask = np.asarray([x in s for x in unique_vals])
df.loc[mask[key]]
```